# QGIS 2.16 Merge lacks folder option

Tags: qgis, merge, qgis-processing

I've installed QGIS 2.16 and have noticed that the Merge (Vector Menu>Data Management) doesn't appear to have a Folder option anymore. This was the option that allowed you to process/merge a complete folder without having to load layers into your project/workspace first. I've had a look at the changelog for QGIS 2.16 - although fTools have been replaced by Processing tools I can't see why the extra functionality has been removed.

Comment: Can you try something? With QGIS 2.16 Processing became a core plugin - you might have to delete the .qgis2/python/plugins/processing folder so that the old plugin doesn't conflict with the upgraded one. Try that and let me know if it brings back the old functionality you're looking for.

Comment: I'd say make a feature request https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: Thanks Matthias and SaultDon. SaultDon - I uninstalled / deleted all versions and related folders before installing 2.16. From what I gather the replacement Merge (see AndreJs answer below) has lost this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the drop of ftools, there is no chance to merge a whole folder of shapefiles from the GUI anymore. It should be possible with ogr2ogr on the commandline: http://www.northrivergeographic.com/ogr2ogr-merge-shapefiles ,
but you have to be sure only merging files of the same geometry type.

The `Merge Vector layers` algorithm only deals with loaded layers from the canvas. This is more or less what the SAGA module of the same name already does, but far less than ftoools provided.

I reported the bug at https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15321. Lets see how the developers deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Hopefully the functionality will get added in in time for the next QGIS release!

Comment: Unfortunately, the developers don't want to. You are encouraged to use the batch processing instead. Or keep a copy of QGIS 2.14 in a safe place ...

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, there is the **Merge shapes** plugin which has the same basic functionality of the fTools' Merge tool:

[image: Merge shapes plugin]

You can download this from the menubar:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
```

Comment: @user77875 - Most welcome, I agree in that they should bring back the old tool but according to the [bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15321) by AndreJ, it would seem they have rejected it :(

Comment: It would appear they have. Shame, because although they suggest batch processing as a workaround, it really isn't as quick as pointing to a directory / folder.